# Wrapping a path around three cylinders

Tags: modifiers

I  added a shrinkwrap modifier to a path to wrap it around three joined cylinders.
How can I make the path follow closer the outer surface? (cf. screenshot)
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to keep the modifier, or just apply it after?

Comment: I can apply it, I want to use the wrapped path for an array of objects placed along it.

Comment: This solution might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118352/drawing-a-belt-around-a-gear

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is temporary extruding the path vertices (as it is a mesh if I see well), then apply the shrinkwrap modifier and delete the previously created vertices.

Make so just add surfaces so that the modifier can do a projection (mode 'project/on surface' and 'back'):

[image]

Projection wll be done along the normals, so I think here you need to extrude along Z. If not the path won't stay horizontal.

---

Edit (if that matters...): I previously misunderstood the question, thinking you wanted to tangent the path around the cylinders. This is not the case, but, eventually, this approach can interest someone:

Transform the cylinders into a convex hull:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that my path is generated from a vertex point to which I added and applied  a screw modifier, so it's a helix going round the three cylinders. I tried your method with extrusion, but the projection option in the modifier does not give the result I want. I does actually nothing.

Comment: @Wilbur, helix should work too. Have you tried? Just care about extruding along Z. If that is not working, can you upload your blend file?

Comment: @Wilbur possibly also, depending on the orientation of the extrusion, switch the projection parameters in the modifier (front/back and negative/positive)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6351" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6351/)

Comment: I tried several parameters, but I does not work for me.

Comment: Uncheck Z (no axis checked), direction: negative, cull face: back. And of course the cylinders should be a bit more height.

Comment: That does it if I rescale the helix a bit, thank you very much. One more question: Is it possible to add a modifier to this helix path going round my three cylinders which regulates the amount it penetrates the convex space between the cylinders?